# CSS: background-size cover but not allowing image to grow past its own width

Tags: css

If I am using `background-size: cover;` for a background image and that image is only 800px wide but the viewport is 1500px wide, how can I make it so that the image does not exceed its own width? (I don't want it stretched any larger than it's original size.)

```
header.hero { 
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 390px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: That's what cover does though. If your images are a certain size you can change the background-size to cover at a certain screen width?

Comment: does width:100% works in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css:

`max-width: 800px;`

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't want to add a CSS definition every time I use a different
>   image...

So you can try add CSS properties:

`width: auto;` - your image width will be scale to img `height`

`max-width: 100%;` - your image never will be wider than container wrapper

Comment: It's a background image, not an `<img>`